# How to deal with a captured caster (beside killing)?

Tags: dnd-5e

I am wondering how both society in general and the player group in particular can deal with an overpowered evil or at least hostile caster. While our group kills during the fight, they don't want to kill someone who is more or less defenceless at that moment. But just setting them free after questioning is also not a viable option.

Also, concerning the general society I don't find the idea of a prison where a large group of high level caster cast Antimagic Field hourly plausible.
Are there any other ways to suppress or remove the ability to manipulate the Weave beside killing or severely maiming?

If you have ideas or references to official descriptions, I'd appreciate it. The setting is Forgotten Realms (Sword Coast).

Comment: At least related: [How do I keep spellcasters from casting while in jail?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/55793), [How can we prevent a sorcerer with the Subtle Spell metamagic option from casting?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/62509)

Comment: But where are my manners? Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already and see the [help] or ask us here in the comments (use @ to ping someone) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!

Comment: Are you the DM or player?

Comment: What level are you at this point?

Comment: Related: [How can I have a villain restrain PCs in an intelligent way without killing or disabling some or all of them?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/181353/how-can-i-have-a-villain-restrain-pcs-in-an-intelligent-way-without-killing-or/181368#181368)

Comment: Hi. Sorry for closing your question, but idea generation is poor fit for the Q&A format of this site. If you can narrow it down to specific problem with answers that can be objectively judged good or bad, or consider [asking it on one of the RPG forums](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5449/ive-been-told-my-question-is-better-suited-to-a-forum-but-where-should-i-go).

Comment: Thank you for the links and welcome! Sorry, that I haven't found the related questions myself.